# How to add custom parameter for keen io Web Auto-Collection

Tags: keen-io

I am using keen io Web Auto-Collection events like page views, clicks and form submission. I want to add custom parameters  like user ID, Org ID, Org Name to these events. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [extend events](https://github.com/keen/keen-tracking.js#extend-events) method to add additional properties to the events being sent with auto-collector.

```js
// Extend events for a single collection
client.extendEvent('transaction', {});
client.extendEvent('transaction', function(){
 return {};
});

// Extend events for all collections
client.extendEvents({});
client.extendEvents(function(){
 return {};
});

// Example usage

var userProps = {
 full_name: 'User Dude',
 email: 'name@domain.com',
 id: 'f1233423h',
 username: 'userdude213'
};

// Include a predefined 'user' object with every purchase event
client.extendEvent('purchases', {
 'user': userProps
});

// Include a predefined 'user' object with every event
client.extendEvents({
 'user': userProps
});

// Include a dynamic 'keen.timestamp' property with every event
client.extendEvents(function(){
 return {
  keen: {
   timestamp: new Date().toISOString()
  }
 };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a little snippet that I'm using to push extended data into Keen IO Web Auto-Collection:

```
window.keenWebAutoCollector.onload(function(){

    var userProps = {
        username : "Any given username",
        uid  : 123,
        other: "data"
    };

    window.keenWebAutoCollector.tracker.extendEvents({
        'user': userProps
    });
});
```

This snippet needs to be added after the code for the Auto-Collector (https://keen.io/docs/streams/web-auto-collection/).

And it will augment the `user` property for all the collections events triggered by the Auto-Collector (Pageviews, Clicks and Form Submissions).